# Laravel update upload using AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, laravel

This is the code for editing uploaded image and title, I don't know how to pass the id to the controller:
**Here form**

```
<form role="form" name="campaignForm" id="campaignForm" action="" method="POST"  enctype="multipart/form-data">
 <input type="hidden" class="form-control" name="id" id="id">
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="title_edit" id="title_edit" autofocus>
  <p class="errorTitle text-center alert alert-danger hidden"></p>
 <input type="file" name="image" id="image" autocomplete="off" placeholder="" class="form-control">

 <button type="button" id="btn-edit" class="btn btn-success add" data-dismiss="modal">Add</button>
</form>
```

**Ajax**

```
   $("#btn-edit").click(function (e) {
       $.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="_token"]').attr('content')
    }
});

    e.preventDefault();

   var form = document.forms.namedItem("campaignForm"); 
var formData = new FormData(form);

$.ajax({
    'id': $("#id").val(),
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'update-advertisement/',
    contentType: false, 
    data: formData, 
    processData: false, 

    success: function (data) {
 }
```

**route**

```
   Route::post('update-advertisement',['as'=>'update-advertisement','uses'=>'AdverController@updatebanner']);
```

**Controller**
     I dont know if this is correct because the id maybe is not sending correctly

```
     public function updatebanner(Request $request,$id)
   {
   $post = Advertisement::findOrFail($id);
    if ($request->hasFile('image')) { $imagename = time().'.'.$request->file('image')->getClientOriginalExtension();
     $path =$request->file('image')->storeAs('/images', $imagename);
  $post->adver_title=$request->sendthis_title;
  $post->adver_photo=$imagename; 
  $post->save();
  return response()->json($post);
   } }
```

Comment: Edit your question and be specific.You have too many question under a same thread.

Comment: What does this code do now, and what does it not do? It looks like it features a title save and an image upload already.

Comment: Sorry i edited the question i want ajax for sending parameters to update function in controller page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order for the "update" feature to work, you would do very similar things to what you've already done for the "Add" functionality.

1) Make sure you have a route defined for an /update route.  Can you post your routes file above so we can take a look at it?

2) Make sure your route is calling the right controller and the right method inside that controller.

3) Make sure the controller mentioned in step 2 has that method defined.

4) Make an Ajax call with the right data to the new /update route you've defined in step 1.

5) Make sure that the Ajax call in step 4) gets triggered when the user clicks an "update" button or some other action indicating they want to update the original Advertisement.

If you post more of your code, I can give you more specific directions.

Comment: Right now, your route doesn't have an {id} parameter in it, so you can't get the $id variable out of the controller's arguments automatically like that, you'll have to erase it.  With what you currently have you would want to pass the ID as data from within your Ajax call.  If there isn't an ID, you'll know to create a new advertisement.  If there is an ID, you'll know you're updating an existing advertisement.  So for starters, delete that $id in your controller `public function updatebanner(Request $request)` and add the id into your JQuery Ajax data: `data: {'form': formData, 'id': id},`

Comment: unfortunately,didn't work with me, when I use data: {'form': formData, 'id': id}, inseted of data:formData, no parameter will pass to controller, but I changed the $id to $request->id $post = Advertisement::findOrFail($request->id); I tried this and working fine :D

Comment: @mate Glad you figured it out!  Hope I was able to help.